# jquery datatable select not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have written this code for my datatable

```
$(function(){
    var $oltable=$("#owner-lead-table");
    var oltable=$oltable.DataTable({
        // 'serverSide' : true,
        // 'ajax': {
        //  url:"/getAllTenantLeadsNotInOpportunity",
        //  type:"GET",
        //  contentType:"application/json",
        //  data : function(d){
        //      console.log(d);
        //      return JSON.stringify(d);
        //  },
        //  dataSrc: function (json) {
        //          console.log(json);
  //                   return json;
  //                },
  //           columns: [
  //            { data:'tenantLeadId' },
  //            { data:'name'},
  //            { data:'email'},
  //            { data:'mobileNumber'},
  //            { data:'qualifier'},
  //            { data:'createdOn'},
  //            { data:'comment'}
  //           ],
        // },
        select:"single"
    });

    $.ajax( {
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/getAllTenantLeadsNotInOpportunity',
                success : function(tenant_leads) {
                            console.log("Inside success function");
                            oltable.clear().draw();
                            $.each(tenant_leads, function(i,lead){
                                oltable.row.add([lead.tenantLeadId,lead.name,lead.email,lead.mobileNumber,lead.qualifier,lead.createdOn,lead.comment]).draw(false);

                        });

                }
            });
});
```

The datatable version is 1.10.10.
The fact is select :'single' is not working as it is supposed to select only a single row when table is clicked . By select I mean selection in the user interface. But it is working in other applications . I want the select : ' single' to work as it is supposed to.

Comment: You must include the select plugin files _after_ the dataTables files. I.e `dataTables.select.min.js` and `select.dataTables.min.css` _after_ `jquery.dataTables.js` ...

Comment: After doing that it worked but alternating rows are not being selected properly. The white rows are properly selected , but the light brown rows are not getting colored and the text is disappearing. Here is my table's html code :- <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
     <table id="owner-lead-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th >Lead Id</th>
        <th >Name</th>
        <th >Email</th>
        <th >Mobile Number</th>
        <th >Qualifier</th>
        <th >Created On</th>
        <th >Comment</th>
       </tr>

Comment: This is just a CSS issue, if you create a fiiddle that replicates the behaviour I am sure you will get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fall in the same problem, I solved using the [invalidate](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().invalidate()) method instead of clear and add rows again.

Comment: I am not sure how exactly this solved your problem. Can you elaborate?